# Selecting data from multiple columns

Tags: dataset, filtering

Mathematica has almost the following example in the documentation:

```
dataset = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> 7|>, <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y","c" -> 9|>, 
 <|"a" -> "-", "b" -> "z", "c" -> "-"|>, <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> 1|>,
 <|"a" -> "-", "b" -> "y", "c" -> "-"|>, <| "a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> 8|>}]
```

The first and last columns are slightly changed compared to the Mathematica
 documentation. To select data based on a criteria related to a column the example is:

```
dataset[Select[#a < 5 &]]
```

What I need to have is – in its simple form:

```
dataset[Select[
  NumberQ[#["a"]] || NumberQ[#["b"]] || NumberQ[#["c"]] &]]
```

However, in the complete form there are 300+ columns, and I want to select all the datasets – but only from a subset of columns (i.e. categories/keys) – that contain numbers. I have the categories of the columns to which `Select` should apply in a list (in this case the list would be `{"a","b","c"}`).

Comment: Could you do something like:

    `dataset[Select[Or @@ (NumberQ /@ Slot /@ {"a", "b", "c", "d"})]]`?

I'm not sure I totally grasp your example; I hadn't seen Dataset used like this before, but it's cool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said that your dataset had over 300 columns, so perhaps the following dataset is a bit more representative:

```
SeedRandom[2];
dataset = Dataset @ Table[
    AssociationThread[{"a","b","c","d","e"}, RandomChoice[Range[2]~Join~{"-",u,v,w,x,y,z}, 5]],
    {10}
]
```

[image]

Then, if you want to select rows where there's a number in columns `a`, `b` or `c`, you can do the following:

```
With[{slots = Slot/@{"a","b","c"}},
    dataset[Select[AnyTrue[slots, NumberQ]&]]
]
```

[image]

Comment: After playing around with the first solution, I came to realise this one is what I actually need, as I need to select the columns/categories in which to test this. Beautiful, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
Select[AnyTrue  @ NumberQ] @ dataset
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for:

```
Select[NumberQ[#"a"] || NumberQ[#"b"] || NumberQ[#"c"] &]@dataset[All, {"a", "b", "c"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
    Select[NumberQ[#a] & || NumberQ[#b] & || NumberQ[#c] &]@dataset
```